# Publishing app with iAd but no completed contract

Tags: ios, xcode

Would it be possible to submit an app with [iAd](https://developer.apple.com/iad/) in it, without having your iAd contract completed? Since it would be like [7-14 days](http://appreviewtimes.com) for Apple to review the app and publish it.

Could I submit my app now, and do the iAd contract tomorrow and everything will be fine?

Answer (score 1):

You can submit your app and use the waiting period to complete meta-data and surrounding materials.

**Try submitting your app.** If the app passes the automated checks, then you have a few days to sort out the contract.

As [@jherran](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/187798/1860) mentions, you will need the iAd contract completed before the app review takes place.

Answer (score 0):

No, the iAd contract must be up and running the moment your app is reviewed, otherwise your app will be rejected.